# Scrapy use xpath crawl ul class is no working

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I crawl this web site
https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_main.html/id=7819

I use `scarpy shell 'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_main.html/id=7819'` on my terminal

I want to crawl the six `li` href under the `ul`
[image]

When i want to get the `li` tag i type command `response.xpath('//ul[@class="trailer_list imglist slick-initialized slick-slider"]/li')` but get a empty list `[]`

I try to type this command `response.xpath('//div[@class="l_box_inner"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()`
Here is what i get:

```
In [14]: response.xpath('//div[@class="l_box_inner"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
Out[14]: 
[u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/name_main/1000',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/name_main/2595',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/video/%E9%81%8A%E6%88%B2%E5%A4%9C%E6%AE%BA%E5%BF%85%E6%AD%BB-%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E9%A0%90%E5%91%8A-095130014.html?movie_id=7819',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189047',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189050',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189053',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189056',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189059',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189062',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/post/169756772517/\u5091\u68ee\u8c9d\u7279\u66fc\u6372\u9032\u5931\u63a7\u904a\u6232\u591c-\u5168\u662f\u4ed6\u60f9\u7684\u798d']
```

But i just want to get the six href they id is 189047'189050'189053'189056'189059'189062

What is the correct xpath command if i just want to get the `li` six href ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in 1st you should use //before li ex:'response.xpath('//ul[@class="trailer_list imglist slick-initialized slick-slider"]//li')'

Comment: please add input html code for proper response.

Comment: Thanks for your respond , i get an answer and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the target `ul` has fewer classes in scrapy response compared to the source as rendered by browser :

```
response.xpath('//ul[@class="trailer_list imglist"]/li/a/@href').extract()
```

output :

```
[u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189047',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189050',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189053',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189056',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189059',
 u'https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/movieinfo_photos.html/id=7819?movie_photo_id=189062']
```

Comment: Awesome ! It works ! What do you  mean fewer classes in scrapy response. I just set full of the class name is not right ?

Comment: @徐博俊 , class names `imglist`, `slick-initialized` and `slick-slider` are absent in initial page source and added dynamically while page rendering in browser

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for your explanation , i get it now.